# Where do I find project templates for asp.net core 1.0 rc2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

The project templates that are available in Visual Studio 2015 for asp.net all depend on RC1.

Some digging led me to the [list of changes between RC1 and RC2](https://github.com/aspnet/announcements/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20milestone%3A1.0.0-rc2), which showed me that there's been some renaming (WebApplication is now WebHost), but the number of other breaking changes that are there suggest that, since I've only just started, it'd be easier to start over with an updated project template.

Except that I can't find one.

Are updated project templates available?  Where do I find them?

Comment: It is nightly builds only so you have to wait till next month when Microsoft gets everything ready.